# Echo Alignment Format

Tags: php, html

can someone tell me why my

```
echo '<p align=center><h3>'.$_SESSION['userName']."'s Profile Page. </h3>'
echo ' ................'
echo ' ................'
echo ' ................ </p>'
```

doesn't work?

It still end up like this (not in the center)

[image]

Comment: `align` as an attribute is dead/gone. That's oldschool html. You should be using css. `<p style="text:align: center"> `

Comment: @MarcB, that should be `text-align:`

Comment: woops, right... and too late to edit now.

Comment: @MarcB still not working guys

Comment: @rnevius still not working tho :\

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
echo '<p style="text-align:center"><h3>'.$_SESSION['userName'].'\'s Profile Page. </h3>';
echo ' ................';
echo ' ................';
echo ' ................ </p>';
```

You missed the center statement and the ; at the end of a each line. 
And maybe the " behind the session is erroneous

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I did include all the ";" sign in the end of each line. Anyway, it still doesn't move tho :\

Comment: Yes you need to do more than add the ";" like I wrote. Did you add the style attribute and fixed the " ?

Comment: Hi, nevermind about my questions above. I finally decided to use class jumbotron to contain all of these informaiton. Thank you :)